# Setter function for shared_ptr

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, rvalue-reference

I want to write an class that optimizes a parameter. I thought the following interface would be desirable:

```
class Optimization {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Part> getParameter() const {
        return m_parameter;
    }
    void setParameter(const std::shared_ptr<Parameter>& parameter) {
        m_parameter = parameter;
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Paramter> m_parameter;
};
```

Now sometimes I may not be interested in the starting value of the parameter so I would like to call setParameter like this:

```
setParameter(std::make_shared(Parameter(...)));
```

(now I guess it makes more sense why there is a getter function)
So as I understand it the setParameter function is not taking advantage that I am passing an rvalue to setParameter.

So my question is how can I solve this?

Should I add another function

```
void setParameter(std::shared_ptr<Parameter>&& parameter) {
            m_parameter = std::move(parameter);
        }
```

Does this avoid unneccessary copies?
Or would a universal reference, maybe like this:

```
template<typename T>
void setParameter(T&& parameter) {
            m_parameter = std::forward<T>(parameter);
        }
```

be a better solution?

Answer (score 3):

The right implementation is like below

```
void setParameter(std::shared_ptr<Parameter> parameter) {
    m_parameter = std::move(parameter);
}
```

1. rvalue will be moved to `parameter` and `parameter` will be moved to `m_parameter`. Two moves, like you want.
2. lvalue will be copied to `parameter` and  `parameter` will be moved to `m_parameter`. One copy and one move, the similar like with const reference, plus cheap moving that will be optimized.

You can read about this in the book "Effective C++" of Scott Meyers.

Answer (score 1):

`std::piecewise_construct` is a constexpr flag which can be used to indicate piecewise construction of a data object.

Explanatory comments inline

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct Parameter
{
    // some constructor
    Parameter(int, int);
};

class Optimization {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<Parameter> getParameter() const {
        return m_parameter;
    }

    // original overload
    void setParameter(const std::shared_ptr<Parameter>& parameter) {
        m_parameter = parameter;
    }

    // rvalue overload
    void setParameter(std::shared_ptr<Parameter>&& parameter) {
        m_parameter = std::move(parameter);
    }

    // piecewise overload which forwards arguments
    template<typename...Args>
    void setParameter(std::piecewise_construct_t, Args&&...args)
    {
        m_parameter = std::make_shared<Parameter>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Parameter> m_parameter;
};


int main()
{
    auto o = Optimization();

    // original
    o.setParameter(std::make_shared<Parameter>(1,2));

    // equivalent to...

    o.setParameter(std::piecewise_construct, 1, 2);
}
```